# What is the power source of Kang's suit?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

In the movie *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*, Kang the Conqueror has a suit that is used for doing multiple things like telekinesis, energy blasts, etc.

What is the source of energy of his suit? Is it Quantum energy? If so, how did he come to know about it before entering the Quantum Realm?

Comment: He comes from the 31st Century, presumably this is handwaved away with: very advanced future tech and Kang being an incredibly smart person. (Not seen the movie yet so not posting an answer, this is based off of _Loki_ and the comics somewhat).

Comment: The power of the sun, in the palm of his hand!

Comment: You can call it magic if you like and nothing about the film will be different.

Comment: Kangs original suit was based off of Dr Dooms suit which is nuclear powered, so maybe kangs suit is nuclear powered too!!

Comment: The suit has some advanced battery that got recharged when the ship’s power source got fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In the movie, Kang does not have access to his suit until he and Janet finish repairing the power source for his ship.  It can then be inferred that his suit draws power from the same source.  It is not fully explained what exactly that power source is though....